# Java- executor service shutdown at class level field

Tags: java, spring, executorservice

I have ExecutorService at class level.

There is a rest point 'url'. So, user will call this API 'n' number of times per day.

How to shutdown the executor service if I define it class level?

CLASS LEVEL: (not sure how to shutdown executor service)

```
public class A {
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    @GET("/url")
    public void executeParallelTask() {
        try {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    }
            });
        }
        finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(12,TIMEUNIT.HOURS)
        }
```

If I shutdown executor service in finally block, when next request comes at rest point, I’m getting Thread Pool size is empty and couldn’t handle the request.

I’m aware of method level like below.

```
public void executeParallelTask() {
    executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    });
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
```

Comment: When do you want it to shut down?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. You have a regular field `executorService` in your example.

Comment: if you make that `static` then you access it as `A.executorService`

Comment: yes it's a normal field. Is it required to shutdown the executor service which is there as regular field?

Comment: You can create a `@PreDestroy` annotated method that shuts it down. Then when the bean is getting unloaded, it will shut down.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try with @PreDestroy and update the status soon here

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a shutdown hook.

```
static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (executorService.isShutdown()) {
                    return;
                }
                log.debug("executorService shutting down...");
                executorService.shutdown();
                executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                log.debug("executorService shutdown");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error(e, e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when is this static block executed? Does it ensures that this static block executes only after executionService.submit() or .execute() has been initiated?

Comment: The static block is executed when the class it's in is loaded and initialized by the JVM.  The shutdown hook added by the static block is executed as the JVM is exiting.  Try it out to see it for yourself.